# Facing error while upgrading KAFKA version in quarkus

Tags: maven, apache-kafka, quarkus, quarkus-kafka

I am using Quarkus version - 2.4.2.Final in my application. I am trying to upgrade the Kafka version to 3.3x

I have a multimodule maven project, module A and module B using module C as a child module
Here's my existing pom.xml

```xml
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
<quarkus-plugin.version>2.4.2.Final</quarkus-plugin.version>
<quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-universe-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
<quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus</quarkus.platform.group-id>
<quarkus.platform.version>2.4.2.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
<surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
```

The Kafka lib that I am using in module A

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The Kafka lib I am using in module B

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-kafka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The Apache Kafka lib is added as a dependency in the mention quarkus-kafka-dependencies.

So I made some changes in pom.xml as shown below:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

but i got the following error while building the application -> mvn clean install

```
Unable to properly register the hierarchy of the following classes for reflection as they are not in the Jandex index:
        - javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory (source: KafkaProcessor > javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule)
        - org.jose4j.jwk.HttpsJwks (source: KafkaProcessor > javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule)
        - org.jose4j.jwk.JsonWebKey (source: KafkaProcessor > javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule)
        - org.jose4j.jwk.VerificationJwkSelector (source: KafkaProcessor > javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule)
        - org.jose4j.jwt.consumer.JwtConsumer (source: KafkaProcessor > javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule)
        - org.jose4j.keys.resolvers.VerificationKeyResolver (source: KafkaProcessor > javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule)
Consider adding them to the index either by creating a Jandex index for your dependency via the Maven plugin, an empty META-INF/beans.xml or quarkus.index-dependency properties.
```

I tested my application in gamma env, and it is working fine. the main cause of my concern is this post https://quarkus.io/blog/quarkus-2-6-0-final-released/ where it was mentioned that by 2.6.0.Final, Kafka 3.0.x will be supported.

Can you please advise what I am missing because my code should not work as mentioned in the document as I am using Quarkus 2.4.2.Final only

Comment: Have you at least tried to create `an empty META-INF/beans.xml` as the output says?

Comment: Yes, I did add an empty META-INF/beans.xml, but still i am receiving the warning